# Resize a div when printing

Tags: javascript, printing, header, resize

I have a div of a gridview that needs to be printed.  I am using a CallPrint JavaScript method to print the div.  I need to add a header and also re-size the div to fit the page better.  Here is the CallPrint method.

```
    function CallPrint(strid) {
        var prtContent = document.getElementById(strid);
        var WinPrint =
        window.open('', '', 'letf=0,top=0,width=800,height=550,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
        WinPrint.document.write(prtContent.innerHTML);
        WinPrint.document.close();
        WinPrint.focus();
        WinPrint.print();
        WinPrint.close();
        prtContent.innerHTML = strOldOne;
    }    //Generating Pop-up Print Preview page
```

Comment: You don't ask any questions here.

Comment: Instead of js why don't you write a dedicated CSS file for media="print"? (take a look here: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/)

Comment: This was helpful...it made it much easier to print and style how the page should look! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not the way to go.

Instead you should have something like `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css" />` at the top of your html file, and change that element by providing cutom CSS  for the print.

Here for more reading : http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/

Comment: It needs to be a dynamic header based on the product/vehicle code they select.  Is there anyway to make a header that will show the code selected using this method?

Comment: This worked as it did resize it when showing in the print preview....however when you print it does not change the size.  Any suggestions on this problem?